# UIButton GIF Background Image

Tags: objective-c

How can I use a `GIF` image as `UIButton` Image Background?

```
        UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img1"];
        UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img2"];
        UIImage *img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img3"];

        // GIF ImageView
        _btnGIF.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1, img2, img3, nil];
        _btnGIF.imageView.animationDuration = 0;
        [_btnGIF.imageView startAnimating];

        //[_btnGIF setBackgroundImage:GIF forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Seems trivial thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your button with an image, so it can create it properly.

For example:

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img1"];
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img2"];
UIImage *img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_img3"];

[_btnGIF setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


// GIF ImageView
_btnGIF.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1, img2, img3, nil];
_btnGIF.imageView.animationDuration = 0;
[_btnGIF.imageView startAnimating];
```